# How to define sender's name in golang net/smtp.sendmail?

Tags: go, smtp, sendmail

My question is short, I have a golang application from which I am trying to send an email using net/smtp.sendmail:

This is the command which I am going to use

```
smtp.SendMail(server, auth, **from**, to, msg)
```

No usually people pass the sender's email address to **from**. Is there anyway I can pass a sender's name as well?

So the recipient will get an email from:

```
Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
```

instead of an email from

```
<foo@bar.com>
```

I checked the official documentation and dozens of examples online but could not find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add it to the `msg` for example, extending the example from the [official docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail) you could use:

```
msg := []byte("From: the name <sender@example.org>\r\n" +
        "To: recipient@example.net\r\n" +
        "Subject: discount Gophers!\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "This is the email body.\r\n")
```

Notice the: `From: the name <sender@example.org>`

> The msg parameter should be an RFC 822-style email with headers first, a blank line, and then the message body. The lines of msg should be CRLF terminated. The msg headers should usually include fields such as "From", "To", "Subject", and "Cc".

Comment: That did it, thank you! I did not notice the collapsed examples.